# Who gets email warnings about deprecated ARM API usage

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, subscription

I'm using Terraform and a Gitlab pipeline to create some **container apps** resources in azure. Modifying some of them during runtime with **`azure-cli`**. The credentials I am using to actually do the modifications are **tenant_id/subcription_id/client_id/client_secret where client_id and client_secret belong to an App principal.**

Now, I received an email from Azure with the content:

> `Retirement of Azure Container Apps API versions 2022-06-01-preview and 2022-11-01-preview
>
> You're receiving this notice because you currently use Azure Resource  Manager API version 2022-06-01-preview or 2022-11-01-preview to manage Azure Container Apps.
>
> Starting on 16 November 2023, you won't be able to manage Azure  Container Apps using version 2022-06-01-preview or 2022-11-01-preview of the Azure Resource Manager API.
>
> Required action:-
> If you're using Azure Resource Manager API version 2022-06-01-preview or 2022-11-01-preview to manage Azure Container Apps, please update your API requests to use version 2023-04-01-preview or later. Management operations using the retired API versions may fail after the retirement date.`

This information is very useful, **however I would like to understand why my email address is the recipient.** This email address belongs to an **azure account that has owner-role** in the **subscription**, However there are **other people that share this role with me (or have contributor role)** but **did not receive the same email.**

I was the original developer creating the system but by now I'm only accidentally still in the subscription, another team (the other contributors in the subscription) are in charge of maintenance for the system.

***Which action actually initiates the sending of this email and how can I configure/have influence on who is actually getting this email?***

***EDIT:
Thanks to the answer @SiddheshDesai and digging once more, it turned out that the other account having the "Owner"-role also received the message, only the ones with "Contributor" didn't.***

Answer (score 1):

According to this  MS Document -  [Change contact information for an Azure billing account - Microsoft Cost Management | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-azure-account-profile#service-and-marketing-emails) . ***This Email is sent by Azure as a Best practice and a Security recommendation.*** Usually this Email is sent to the Owner of the Subscription who created the Azure account in the First place. The one who creates the Azure account subscription also gets assigned a Service Administrator role which has Privileged access on Billing and all the management tasks on Azure. You can change the Default Email Address by referring the steps below:-

***Select your Azure Portal > Top Right > Portal Settings > My information >  Email setting > Email address > Change the email address > Apply :-***

[image]